# How to solve this kind of glitch?

Tags: armature, weight-painting

Video reference: https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EQFx3_UeUclJlL1ZqIPqQdoBo6LdgknWJJWmZkgudn8Icg?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=l21EQ5

No matter I substract or add weight, it doesn't solve the glitch

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: AgitAngst has answered correctly imho but do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Select these vertices in *Edit Mode* and manually remove/add to group in Vertex Groups